# In Kivy, how do I prevent pixel images from becoming blurry when enlarged?

Tags: python, image, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I'm using small sprites as images, and they become blurry when enlarged.  How do I fix this?

Here is the source image:
[image]

[image: blurry images]

```
import kivy
kivy.require("1.10.0")
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder

class Container(BoxLayout):
    pass

class TestName(App):
    def build(self):
        Builder.load_string("""
<Container>:
    id: contain
    Image:
        source: "smile.png"
        allow_stretch: True
        """)
        root = Container()
        return root

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestName().run()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it by setting `mag_filter` of your image's texture to `nearest`, like this:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder

class Container(BoxLayout):
    pass

class TestName(App):
    def build(self):
        Builder.load_string("""
<Container>:
    id: contain
    image: image
    Image:
        source: "smile.png"
        allow_stretch: True
        id: image
        """)
        root = Container()
        root.image.texture.mag_filter = 'nearest'
        return root

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestName().run()
```

Comment: Thank you so much!